# Why can't I install Talib correctly?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install `ta-lib` from a ubuntu console, I had a problem with python versions .. then activate virtual env.
But the problem is that if I install Ta-lib from the file, then when I am going to execute my program the following error comes up:

```
import talib as ta
ImportError: No module named 'talib'
```

I don't understand why if I already have the ta-lib library installed

Comment: What makes you think it is already installed?

Comment: How did you install it specifically?

Comment: What makes you think it is already installed? – Scott Hunter 
I installed it in the same way as this video .. and everything went well, the difference is that I installed it in virtual env
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlFSxXP_d9M&t=98s

Comment: Download ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz and:

$ tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

$ cd ta-lib/

$ ./configure --prefix=/usr

$ make

$ sudo make install

Comment: Another problem I have is that when I enter the virtual environment I cannot install using pip: Building wheel for TA-Lib (setup.py) ... \ ... and does not continue